# How to delete all paragraphs where a pattern is not present?

Tags: vim

I keep a log-book of the meetings in which I took part.

Each meeting :

- is separated by a blank line (-> each meeting is a paragraph)
- is folded thanks to an expression
- contains a line with the corresponding tags : ACME, GMBH, SARL, etc…

When I want to make a review of all the meetings I had with, e.g., ACME,

- I create a scratch buffer (:%y, followed by :tabnew, followed by paste)
- and I wish to eliminate all paragraphs where ACME does not figure.

This is where I have a problem.

I know how to search/delete by lines :

```
:v/ACME/d
```

But how do I do that by paragraph (so as to keep the whole paragraph where ACME figures, and not the only line of tags) ?

NB : the pattern ACME can figure more than once in those paragraphs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works:

```
let @r="" | execute("g/acme/ normal \"Rdap") | %d | put r
```

It goes to every paragraph containing "acme", and delete it **appending** to register r. Then deletes everything and puts register r.

As you see, basic trick is using capital letter register to add to it, instead of replacing its content. This also requires resetting the register at the beginning, to discard previous register contents.

This works ok for paragraphs with multiple occurrences of "acme", as the whole paragraph is deleted after the first match, and so, it's not matched again.

Comment: Wow, really surprised that `execute` with parentheses doesn't give a syntax error. I've never seen this before, it's normally written `execute "..."`.

Comment: @glts same here! ;)  I even searched `:h execute()` to see if there is a function..   anyway, this does the work +1!! and it would be better if at beginning save the value of `@r` and at the end restore it.

Comment: @glts I tried `echo ("foobar")` and `echo ("foo").("bar")` work too. it seems that as long as the expression between the `()` return a valid string (or could be converted into str), it would work.  the `( and )` enhanced the readability.  :)

Comment: @eleom : It works superbly, so I accept the answer and add +1 ! Just one (minor) question : how come you do not use, in that case v instead of g ?

Comment: @ThG Using `:g` you locate each "acme" occurrence. For each "acme" occurrence, you get the containing paragraph. So you have a way to separate paragraphs containing "acme" from those that don't. If you start the other way (`:v`), you get each line that doesn't have "acme" in it. Those lines could happen in any kind of paragraph (those containing "acme" and those that don't). So, that path doesn't lead you anywhere.

Comment: @eleom : this is - once explained by you - very clear. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

I would do it with awk, in vim you could:

```
%!awk -v RS="" -v ORS="\n\n" '/ACME/'
```

then only paragraphs containing `ACME` will be kept.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I do not have awk on my Android device (only on my computer). Is it impossible in Vim alone ?

Comment: I had tried :v/'{ACME'}/d ... and deleted everything (I still do not understand why). Thanks again.

Comment: @ThG :v and :g won't work, because they process text **line**wise

Comment: OK, I understand now that it won't be easy... Thanks anyhow